# Agrupar um conjunto de medidas em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

Estou com um problema para unir um conjunto de valores.

Eu tenho um sistema de marcação de madeiras. Eu alimento o banco de dados com o comprimento x largura da madeira

Id, id_pedido, comprimento, largura, data

```
Registros:

1, 3, 320, 20, 05-25-2017

2, 3, 320, 25, 05-25-2017

3, 3, 310, 10, 05-25-2017

4, 3, 310, 20, 05-25-2017

5, 3, 190, 15, 05-25-2017
```

Agora eu preciso de uma rotina em PHP ou Mysql que una os resultados para não aparecer duas vezes o mesmo comprimento e dessa forma ele une as medidas pra serem mostradas ao lado desse comprimento.

Exemplo de como ficaria:

```
320-20 x 25

310 - 10 x 20

190 - 15
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Não devemos usar funções da extensão "mysql" pelo seu desenvolvimento ter sido descontinuado. Se vc acrescentar nas tags MySQLi ou PDO eu publico a resposta :)

Comment: Pronto @LeoCaracciolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o group_concat que concatena uma sequencia de campos de acordo com a sua query e grupo definidos. O group_concat é uma função de agregação assim como count(), sum(), etc.

**MySQLi**

```
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "USUARIO";
$senha = "SENHA";
$dbname = "NOME_DB";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
    $query = ('SELECT comprimento, group_concat(largura SEPARATOR " * ") AS lista, SUM(largura) as largura_sum FROM arquivos GROUP BY comprimento');
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['comprimento']." - ";
    echo $row['lista']." Total: ";
    echo $row['largura_sum']."<br>";
}
```

**PDO**

```
$hostname="localhost";  
$username="USUARIO";  
$password="SENHA";  
$db = "NOME_DB";  
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT comprimento, group_concat(largura SEPARATOR " * ") AS lista, SUM(largura) as largura_sum FROM arquivos GROUP BY comprimento') as $row) {  

echo $row['comprimento'] . " - ";  
echo $row['lista']." Total: ";  
echo $row['largura_sum']."<br>"; 

}
```

> Geralmente, o GROUP_CONCAT separa os itens com vírgula:

`item1,item2,item3,item4`

> É possível definir o separador a ser usado, dessa forma:

`GROUP_CONCAT(suacoluna SEPARATOR ' ')`

**Resposta editada para atender comentário do autor pedindo a soma das larguras**

Comment: Então, ele retornou isso:


`comprimento  lista
9.80  [BLOB - 4Bytes]
2.50  [BLOB - 4Bytes]
2.30  [BLOB - 4Bytes]
5.00  [BLOB - 18Bytes]`

Comment: Deu certo! Mais uma dúvida. Veja se pode me ajudar! É possivel eu fazer a soma desses comprimentos direto na query? Por exemplo se ele tem 3 resultados de larguras pro mesmo comprimento, ele somar essas largura (30+14+16 = 60)

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO! Funcionou perfeitamente. Valeu amigo

Answer (score 1):

Você pode concatenar as colunas que representam as dimensões e agrupar os dados:

Tabela:

```
create table test.pedidos
(
    id_pedido int auto_increment primary key,
    comprimento float null,
    largura float null,
    data date null
);
```

Alguns dados:

```
INSERT INTO pedidos
  (comprimento, largura, data)
VALUES
  (320, 20, '2017-05-05'),
  (320, 25, '2017-05-05'),
  (310, 10, '2017-05-06'),
  (320, 25, '2017-05-06'),
  (320, 20, '2017-05-07'),
  (320, 20, '2017-05-08'),
  (300, 100, '2017-05-10')
;
```

E a consulta com as informações que você precisa:

```
SELECT
  concat(comprimento, '-', largura),
  count(1)
FROM pedidos
GROUP BY concat(comprimento, '-', largura);
```

Comment: O resultado que eu tive foi assim:

`concat(comprimento, '-', largura)  count(1)
2.30-0.98  1
2.50-0.65  1
5.00-0.21  1
5.00-0.39  1
5.00-0.98  1
9.80-0.32  1
`

como eu faço para tratar esses dados? Ele continua não agrupando as medidas